# Question regarding utf8 inputenc

Tags: floats, errors, symbols

I was working on a project and all of a sudden it stopped compiling, showing lots of errors in unicode characters, unicode sequences and such. All pointing to utf8 inputenc in my preamble.

Is it a bug or something related ? Im getting this kind of errors:

```
 /chapters/chapter2.tex, line 124
LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `f'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.124 \begin{sidewaystable}[htbf]

Option `f' ignored and `p' used.
```

And this:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char 〗 (U+3017)

(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Ill be very grateful if you could help me

Gab

ps. I tried replacing utf8 with utf8x and it doesn´t work either.

Comment: Which latex engine do you use and which version?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I use sharelatex, im really no advanced user, is there other compiler i should use ?

Comment: the float option error is unrelated to inputenc, you have `htbf`  which is a syntax error, what did you intend `f` to mean? You could just delete the f, or better replace it by `p`

Comment: there isn't a symbol relating to  〗 in the standard tex math fonts, you could look in the font catalogue to see if there is something, or just use `]`